# xCode console output empty after printing string

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I can't see any output to the console in xCode after printing a string "Button pressed", I have tested the code when the button is pressed so I am sure that the code that prints is reached. Here is the method:

```
func onRatingButton(button: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed")
}
```

(Swift)
The code is executed when a button is pressed.

This is what my console looks like:

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzjQ1.png)

Please help if you can, thanks :)

- Update

Thank you everyone who helped, I was apparently looking at the wrong thing :)

Comment: Can you print text from anywhere else in the code? How is this function invoked?

Comment: the screenshot is a part of the debug area, yes, but there is no console there. [This](http://i.imgur.com/GcgZDy5.png) is a screen with the console. Notice 2 blue buttons on the lower right part of the screen (they can be gray), you might want to play with those, particularly with the one on the right.

Comment: Thanks 4oby, that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console is collapsed, you need to click the little icon on the right :

[image]

so it becomes blue :

[image]

Comment: Cmd-Shift-C will also bring up the console.